# Regarding building application in Spring JMS

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I am a new bie to the world of `Spring JMS`, I have read the manning *Spring in action* particular for `JMS`, I have also gone with through this [url](http://briansjavablog.blogspot.in/2012/09/spring-jms-tutorial-with-activemq.html) and it helped me lot.I have also gone through the official spring reference and discovers the JMS templates also, Now my query is could you please advise me some more urls so that when, I am going to build a small first application which will put data in queue and another app will read data from that queue, so I will be using `Active MQ`, please share some url and examples to grasp more and that will help me to build the application and explore the world of spring JMS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Follow these links in order:

1. [Using spring to send jms messages](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-spring-jmstemplate-to-send-jms.html)
2. [Using spring to receive jms messages](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-spring-to-receive-jms-messages.html)
3. [Tuning jms message consumption in spring](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.se/2010/05/tuning-jms-message-consumption-in.html)
4. [Creating robust jms application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JMS6.html)